# Python 3 MemoryError for input split

Tags: python-3.x, input

When trying to split input

```
n_list = input()
n_list = n_list.split()
```

I'm getting a `MemoryError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "Main.py", line 8, in 
    n_list = n_list.split()
MemoryError
```

Comment: What is being input? It would have to be something big.

Comment: Considering that `input` stops at the first new line and `split()` without parameters splits on newlines, this should only be creating a list with one item, which should be a slice of the original string. I don't see how this can happen!

Comment: I was trying to solve this problem https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2715

Comment: Is the problem that the second line is really large, too large to split in the memory space you have available? You could print the first line, telling you the total number, to get a feel for the size. If that's the case, you can't just read everything and split to solve the problem.